# how to use Scrapy post the multipart/form-data to the api?

Tags: python, forms, scrapy, multipartform-data

Here is an example of a multipart/form-data:

```
-----------------------------265001916915724
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="client_id"

c3cef7c66a1843f8b3a9e6a1e3160e20
-----------------------------265001916915724
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="grant_type"

password
```

when use the requests lib, my successful code is:

```
data = {
    'key': value, 'key': 'value',
}
encoder = MultipartEncoder(
    data, boundary='-----------------------------265001916915724')
headers['Content-Type'] = encoder.content_type
session = requests.session()
session.post(url, headers=headers, data=encoder.to_string(), )
```

but when i use the Scrapy, the failed code :

```
        encoder = MultipartEncoder(
            data, boundary='-----------------------------265001916915724')
        me_length = encoder.len
        headers['Content-Length']= me_length
        me_body = encoder.to_string()
        yield scrapy.Request(urls,method='POST', headers=headers, body=me_body,)
```

**I want to know how to use Scrapy post the multipart/form-data to a api, I get the return status code 400, but the same data in Requests's method can get suceess**

Comment: I think [this could be useful](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/1954)

Comment: Thank you! but in the Scrapy 1.5.0,I can't find the MultipartFormRequest.

Comment: why do you create `me_body` before you create `encoder` ? Check `print(me_body)` .

Comment: @furas encoder = MultipartEncoder(
                data, boundary='-----------------------------41184676334')
            me_length = encoder.len
            me_body = encoder.to_string()
            headers['Content-Length']= me_length
            print(encoder.fields)
            print(headers)
            yield scrapy.Request(urls,method='POST', headers=headers, body=me_body,)

Comment: I modify the code ,but I can't get the correct status code.

Comment: you should create minimal working example with real url so we could test it and see problem.

Comment: The real url need so many data fileds , so the whole code is so long. I update the question code. I want to know a success code of Request lib, how to convert the code in Scrapy.